# How to get simultaneous eigenvectors of commuting matrices?

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

So let's say there are two square matrices A and B that commute (AB-BA=0). This implies that there must exist some complete set of vectors that are eigenvectors of *both* A and B.

Is there any way to tell Mathematica to find the eigenvectors of *both* A and B? At this point, I can get the eigenvectors of A and then find the eigenvectors of B by taking linear combinations of those for A by hand, but this is obviously not feasible for larger matrices.

Comment: Any special structure (e.g. symmetry, sparseness) in your matrices?

Comment: In particular, I'm thinking about a real symmetric matrix (let's say that's A) and a "parity" operator matrix for B (real, symmetric, all 0's except a single 1 for each row and each column).

Comment: Oh...I just realized that I can take a linear combination (ex. A-1.23456B) and find the eigenvectors of that, where 1.23456 is just some random real number. That, in general, would give me all the eigenvectors, and I could calculate the eigenvalues from there.